# Comments for multiple objects

Tags: mysql

I have 2 objects (articles, products) for which I will have comments. How can I store comments for both objects?

What is a better solution: create an object for each new table (`article_comments`, `product_comments`) or store comments in one table and create a new table for each object contains a link between the object table and comments table?

[image: DB model]

Comment: Comments table for each entity, otherwise you'll need a mapping table.

Comment: Two tables seems good, just to have that nice separation if you ever need to deal with them as parts conveniently.